# Ensuring Spring Integration deployment's JMS listener threads are cleaned up on Tomcat undeploy

Tags: spring, tomcat7, ibm-mq, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a simple Spring Integration application which runs on Tomcat (v7.0.x) and consumes messages off a Websphere MQ Queue. When I un-deploy the WAR from the Tomcat server, the WAR un-deploys okay but, a JMS listener thread is left running on the Tomcat server which will still consume messages off the Websphere MQ Queue. I am therefore assuming that I am not handling the JMS listener clean up part of the application properly?

Here is the stack I am using:

```
Java 8
Tomcat 7.0.55
Spring Integration 4.0.4
Spring Integration Java Dsl 1.0.0.M3
```

In terms of my SI application's configurations, I have a JmsConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class JmsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Properties jndiProperties;

    private ConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        try {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (MQQueueConnectionFactory)
                ctx.lookup("jms/service/SERVICE_QCF");

            return connectionFactory;

        } finally {
            ctx.close();
        }   
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory());
        connectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

I have an Integration config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory).destination(
                    "SERVICE_QUEUE_NAME"), c -> {
                c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100));
            })
            .channel("request.service.ch").get();
    }
}
```

Web Initialiser config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebInitialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = 
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class, JmsConfig.class,
            IntegrationConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

During the un-deploy stage I see the following in the catalina logs which may or may not be related:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/service-a] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Is there anything that I have yet NOT set or configured or annotated in order to ensure that the deployment's JMS listener thread is cleaned up from Tomcat's JVM during the WAR's un-deploy stage?

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that JMS listener threads are cleared up upon the application's un-deploy stage, I simply created a CachingConnectionFactory bean with its targetConnectionFactory being that of the MQConnectionFactory. Then, in the Spring Integration flows, I simply pass in the cachingConnectionFactory bean to the JMS adapters instead. I've updated the configs in this post to show this. Cheers, PM.